# How to format 'DateTime.UtcNow' to 23-12-2021-05-31-25 from 23/12/2021 05:31:25 in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

I want to change the `DateTime.UtcNow` to `23-12-2021-05-31-25` from its original: `23/12/2021 05:31:25`.

I have tried to change `DateTime` to string and the replace the `/` and `:` with `-`.

But I got an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

How I can change my date&time representation to `23-12-2021-05-31-25`?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: A `DateTime` type does not have an inherent format.  It is just a number.  Formats only come into play when you display the value to a human.  If you have a string date value it is just a string and needs to be *parsed*.  There are oodles of posts here to help and illuminate

Comment: You ask about `DateTime.UtcNow`, but you also provide a string format date as the "source". So, is your question how to convert `DateTime.UtcNow` to a `string` with a specific format or is it how to parse a string as a `DateTime` and then reformat it to a new `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Just try using the proper date formatting string in `.ToString()`.

So how about this snippet of code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss"));
```

I get an output something like:

```
23-12-2021-05-59-17
```

Does that match your needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
String strTimeNow = timeNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
Console.WriteLine(timeNow);
Console.WriteLine(strTimeNow);
```

Output:

```
12/23/2021 6:06:29 AM
23-12-2021-06-06-29
```

I hope this solves your problem. If not, please let me know.